# Spring Integration Http Outbound to AWS ElasticSearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-integration, aws-elasticsearch

I am trying to use HTTP Outbound gateway to read data from AWS elasticsearch. I am aware of setting up a request-factory to provide username and password credentials. Is there a similar way to provide the AWS access and secret keys?

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway id="httpGatewayToES"
        url="${es.host}/${es.index}/${es.index.mapping}/_search?q=ID:12345" header-mapper="httpHeaderMapper" http-method="GET" request-factory="httpOutboundServiceRequestFactory">
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend do not do that via HTTP. Consider to use AWS Java SDK and `AWSElasticsearch`, respectively.

See the AWS recommendations:

> You can access Amazon ES through the Amazon ES console, the AWS SDKs, or the AWS CLI.
>
> The Amazon ES console lets you create, configure, and monitor your domains. Using the console is the easiest way to get started with Amazon ES.
>
> The AWS SDKs support all the Amazon ES API operations, making it easy to manage your domains using your preferred technology. The SDKs automatically sign requests as needed using your AWS credentials.
>
> The AWS CLI wraps all the Amazon ES API operations, providing a simple way to create and configure domains. The AWS CLI automatically signs requests as needed using your AWS credentials.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/what-is-amazon-elasticsearch-service.html#accessing-amazon-elasticsearch